# How can I count all elements in loop "for in" in Jinja2 templates Django

Tags: django, count, django-templates, jinja2

I tried to use loop:

```
user_list = <QuerySet [<TableUsers: Jane>, <TableUsers: Kate>, <TableUsers: Jons>, <TableUsers: Jacob>, <TableUsers: Jane>, <TableUsers: Jons>, <TableUsers: Jane>]>
```

```
{% for user in user_list %}
  {% if user.name == "Jane" %}
    {{all_count_username_jane}} # this is all count user with name Jane
    {{user.name}}
  {% elif user.name == "Jons" %}
    {{all_count_username_jons}} # this is all count user with name Jons
    {{user.name}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I count all "Jane" and "Jons"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used something like `user_list = SomeModel.objects.all()`, you can replace it by something like

```
from django.db.models import Count

user_list = SomeModel.objects.values('name').annotate(count_names=Count('id'))
```

then also change your template codes to:

```
{% for user in user_list %}
  {% if user.name == "Jane" %}
    {{user.count_names}} # this is all count user with name Jane
    {{user.name}}
  {% elif user.name == "Jons" %}
    {{user.count_names}} # this is all count user with name Jons
    {{user.name}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I used:
user_list  = table_users_all.exclude(Q(user_status=1) | Q(
        user_status=2)).annotate(count_names=Count('id'))
But in template I look:
> 1 Jane, 1 Jane
> 1 Jons, 1 Jons, 1 Jons,

Comment: you right! I changed "annotate" how this is in link https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/db/aggregation.html